# Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context - Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
bindingSub.btnCoinup.setOnClickListener {
    fbFirestore?.collection("users")?.document(fbAuth?.uid.toString())?.get()?.addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            var autoCoin = document.data?.values.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").toLong()
            bindingSub.tvAutoCoin.setText("Coin: ${autoCoin += 1}")
        } else {
            bindingSub.tvAutoCoin.setText("Coin: 0")
        }
    } ?.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        ...
```

> bindingSub.tvAutoCoin.setText("Coin: ${autoCoin += 1}")

I tried really hard to fix this error, but I couldn't fix it.

Even if the code is dirty, I would appreciate it if you understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a new value in this line to the `autoCoin` variable:

```kotlin
bindingSub.tvAutoCoin.setText("Coin: ${autoCoin += 1}")
```

String templates only allow expressions. An expression is something that results in a value of some type, even if that type is Unit and can be on the right hand side of an assignment statement (e.g `val x = 3` assigns the value of the expression `3` to `x`). Some languages (like Java or C++) assignments are expressions, but in Kotlin they are not.

The `x += 1` operator is a special shorthand syntax for `x = x + 1`.

Comment: It can be changed to `++autoCoin` so it assigns but is also an expression.